# Selenium Webdriver SessionNotCreatedException on EC2 Amazon Linux but not locally

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, amazon-ec2

I am running a Selenium web scraper on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux) as root user. This is my initialization setup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sand box")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

... scraping code ...

driver.quit()
```

The versions of ChromeDriver and Chrome match:

```
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 121.0.6167.85
```

```
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 121.0.6167.85
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/my-project/scripts/save.py", line 18, in get_and_save_new_tokens
    new_tokens_raw = scrape_taptools_projects(url)
  File "/home/ec2-user/my-project/scripts/taptools_scraper.py", line 99, in scrape_taptools_projects
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Locally, the code works as intended. Strangely, the code also worked on the EC2 instance up until yesterday. I did not change any settings.

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

I already tried the following:

- I restarted the instance
- I reinstalled google-chrome (121.0.6167.85) on the instance and manually downloaded the aligning version of Chromedriver (121.0.6167.85)
- I rechecked if the code works locally and it did
- I changed the line

```
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Both resulted in the same error message

**Update**
In the meantime I found following fix suggestion:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4403#c35

Adding

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
```

results in the new error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/my-project/scripts/save.py", line 18, in get_and_save_new_tokens
    new_tokens_raw = scrape_taptools_projects(url)
  File "/home/ec2-user/my-project/scripts/taptools_scraper.py", line 101, in scrape_taptools_projects
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60,000)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's embarrassing: I must have accidentally let a space slip into

```
options.add_argument("--no-sand box")
```

The right way to spell it is

```
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```